# How to undo command sudo nautilus

Tags: nautilus, sudo, root

I have typed `sudo nautilus` to make some changes , now I want to come out of the command or undo the command to give access back to root.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just kill the command again:

go the terminal from which you run the command `sudo nautilus` and then press the key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

Or easily just close the terminal by clicking on X, this would kill `nautilus` process

Comment: @Aevi you are welcome friend

Comment: Hi @Aevi, if the answer solves your problem, please mark it as solved.

Comment: How to mark ; i m new to this ask ubuntu.. stack exachange community

Comment: @Aevi you can find many tutorials on line